# What resources are available for iPhone development using AS3?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3

I've just realeased my first game developed for the iPhone using AS3 and the iPhone Packager http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapshot-paintball/id407362440?mt=8&uo=4

I want to take the game to the next level but I am not using the native iPhone SDK so I need some other ideas, I am fresh to iPhone development and it's hard to find good resources, any AS3 developers out there willing to share some links? Highscore frameworks and best practices, connecting to Facebook, ui classes/gestures. Thanks.

Comment: A suggestion: make a free trial version. It will give you more visibility and, in this question, more people might be able to see the game for more insights.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but this seems to be THE gesture library for actionscript. http://gestureworks.com/features/